# How to combine common elements in to one array?

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am trying to combine three arrays into one array. Only keeping the common elements. This is not a duplicate question. I am aware there are other examples online, but that is using int [] and I don't know how to do it with Comparable.

What I need help with:

1. How to add the single combined/updated array to the 2d array.
2. How to count the iterations of each time an element gets compared.
3. If I wanted  how could I change the arrays I have now to a List? - I was thinking maybe that would be easier to add.

I am a newbie to programming and I would appreciate the help. I am trying to learn java just by reading books and searching online.

This is what I have so far.

```
public class Common{

Comparable [] col_1 = {1, 1, 2};
Comparable [] col_2 = {1, 1, 2,3};
Comparable [] col_3= {1, 1, 2,3,4,};
Comparable [][] collections = {col_1, col_2, col_3};
int comparisonCount = 0


public Comparable[] findCommon(Comparable [][] collections){

int i, j, k, x, y;

for(i = 0; i< col_1.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < col_2.length; j++){
        for(k = 0; k < col_3.length; k++){

comparisonCount++;     
// This should be counting but is not...

if(col_1[i].compareTo(col_2[j]) == 0 && col_1[i].compareTo(col_3[k]) ==0){

//keep searching until last element & allow duplicates & add to collections or a temp[]


                }
        }
    }
}

// Here I'm not sure how to add the elements to the collection


for (x = 0; x < collections.length; x++){
    for(y = 0; y< collections[x].length; y++){
        collections [x][y] = ?????? // not sure how to add results here
        }
    }
}


public void setComparisons(int count){
    count = comparisonCount;
}



public int getComparisons(){

    return comparisonCount;
}



public class Sorting {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Common m = new Common();
    //I want to test it from here but I don't know how to initialize each array.        

    for(int x=0; x < m.collections.length; x++){
        for(int y= 0; y< m.collections[x].length; y++){
        System.out.println(m.collections[x][y]);
    }
// what I should be getting is only (1, 1, 2) -  the order is not important really. I just want to learn. 

    }
    System.out.println(m.getComparisons());

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep only common elements in the comparable sets, you can use a TreeSet, that compares elements using the passed comparator.

Also, using a custom comparator you can count how many times elements are compared to each other:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {
    public static Comparable[] findCommon(Comparable[][] collections, Comparator comparator) {
        TreeSet<Comparable> set = new TreeSet<Comparable>(comparator);
        Collections.addAll(set, collections[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < collections.length; i++)
            set.retainAll(Arrays.asList(collections[i]));

        return set.toArray(new Comparable[set.size()]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparable[] col_1 = {1, 1, 2};
        Comparable[] col_2 = {1, 1, 2, 3};
        Comparable[] col_3 = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4};

        Comparable[][] collections = {col_1, col_2, col_3};
        final int comparisonCount = 0;

        CountingComparator comparator = new CountingComparator();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findCommon(collections, comparator)));
        System.out.println(comparator.getComparisonCount());
    }

    private static class CountingComparator implements Comparator<Comparable> {
        private int comparisonCount;

        public int getComparisonCount() {
            return comparisonCount;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Comparable o1, Comparable o2) {
            comparisonCount++;
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers (in order of simplicity):

- Question 2: Why do you need to keep the comparison count? The way you have it, it'll always be the product of the array lengths (`col_1.length * col_2.length * col_3.length`).
- Question 1: Maybe consider using a HashSet (see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). This runs a lot faster than what you have but may not have the same comparison count.
- Question 3: Finally, to be able to add the last collection, you may want to use a list (a `List<Comparable[]> ls` isn't unreasonable). All you'll have to do with the HashSet (assuming you make `HashSet<Comparable> hs = new HashSet<>();`) is `ls.add(hs.toArray())`. Frankly, I don't know why you'd do this since your method is supposed to return `hs.toArray()` instead (in fact, does your code compile, seeing as you're not returning according to the code you've posted?).